# How to use MSBuild when Jenkins is running on Linux

Tags: linux, jenkins, msbuild, containers

I'm trying to set up a build and deploy pipeline in Jenkins for our .net code. The code is not .net Core!

Problem is that our Jenkins farm is running in Kubernetes Pods on Linux. As far as I understand I cannot get MSBuild to run on Linux OS, so one way of solving it is to create a new virtual Windows pc as a Jenkins slave and Install MSBuild there. And then have the Jenkins Master call the slave for building.

But is that the best solution? I'm told that it's an "expensive" solution with our current setup.

Is there another way I could solve this? Is it for example possible to have a container with Windows and MSBuild running on in a Docker container on Linux?

I hope that someone can point me in the right direction or give me inspiration for different solutions - Thanks in advance

Comment: If I were you I would not ask for the the "best" solution rather: Do I know enough to make this happen and is the approach reasonable.

Comment: Yeah thats possible to use a container to run with MSBuild since now Microsoft has release docker images to support `.NET core` environment https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core .

However, before doing this you need to understand how are developers are testing while doing development since the build of software should be in a consistent way throughout till production release, So it won't make sense if dev doing using a windows machine and your Jenkins will use a different pattern.

Comment: You can create build agent on container with Windows and setup project to build on this gent.